# unable to link a jsp to a servlet... fragment not found..?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I am trying to call a servlet from a jsp file but am unable to that. The error message I'm getting is

> The requested resource (/practice/de.vogella.wtp.jspsimple/src/practiceServlet) is not available

This is the jsp code:

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>No of EMPLOYEES</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>No of EMPLOYEES</h1>
<jsp:include page="..\src\practiceServlet" flush="true"/>


</body>
</html>
```

And the servlet code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

import javax.naming.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
//import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
//import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.*;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class practiceServlet
 */
public class practiceServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    //private static DataSource ds; 
    private static Connection conn;
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
    */
    public practiceServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


public void init() throws ServletException{
    try{
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.getMessage();
        }
        //InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//172.20.0.69:1521/orcl","FLEXASK","flexask");
        //ds = (DataSource) ic.lookup("jdbc/OracleDS");
        //conn= ds.getConnection();
    }
    catch(SQLException se){
        throw new ServletException(se);
    }

}
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
      String query = "{? = call FLEXASK.func_practice1}";

      CallableStatement statement = conn.prepareCall(query);
      statement.registerOutParameter(1,java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
      statement.execute();

      int result = statement.getInt(1);
      statement.close();
     out.println("<br><b>" + result + "</b>is the number of Employees in the Database");
    }
    catch(SQLException se){
        se.printStackTrace(out);
    }

}
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public  void destroy() {
    try{
        conn.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

}

One more thing: when I use

```
<jsp:include page="..\src\practiceServlet.java" flush="true"/>
```

instead of

```
<jsp:include page="..\src\practiceServlet" flush="true"/>
```

and access the jsp through browser it shows me the the servlet code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your webapp's WEB-INF directory is a web.xml file.  Your servlet container won't load the `practiceServlet` class, instantiate it, and initialize it as a servlet unless you declare it in web.xml like below.

```
<web-app version="..." xmlns="...">

    <!-- Add the servlet and servlet-mapping tags below 
         inside the root web-app tag. -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>practice</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>practiceServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>practice</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/practiceServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

In your jsp, adjust the relative url to be the url-pattern you used in the web.xml.

```
<jsp:include page="/practiceServlet" flush="true"/>
```

Comment: @ppuskar this is the content of the web.xml  
`<servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>practiceServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>practiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>practiceServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>practiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/practiceServlet</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>`,@Tap

Answer (score 0):

here is what you do to call a servlet :
1)

1. Create a servelet class(which you already did)
2. have a url mapping for your servlet class.
3. the url to which the servlet class is mapped to, and same should be used to call your servlet's code.

I can see you have not mentioned your web.xml for the servlet mapping.
This is a crud explanation, google and learn how servlets are used.

Answer (score 0):

```
configure web.xml for servlet.

<servlet>
        <servlet-name>practice</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>practiceServlet(path for servlet)</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>practice</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/practiceServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Any chance you could expand your answer with some help for the OP (and future people coming across the question!) on how to do this?